# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: in POST request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am creating a post function to save data in a model, Here's the code:

**Views.py**

```
class take_quizapi(CreateAPIView):

    def post(self, request,pk, *args, **kwargs):
        supplier = request.user.supplier

        data = request.data.copy()
        data["supplier_id"] = supplier.user_id
        data["score"] = 0
        data["quiz"] = pk
        print("data is", data)
        serializer = takenquizSerializer(data=data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print("Serializer data", serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

when I call the API from postman it says:

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "supplier_id" violates not-null constraint

But I am clearly providing the `data["supplier_id"] = supplier.user_id`.
What is it that I am doing wrong here ?

Serializers.py

```
class takenquizSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    supplier = ReadOnlyField(source='supplier.supplier_fname')
    class Meta:
        model = TakenQuiz
        fields = "__all__"
```

Models.py

```
class TakenQuiz(models.Model):
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taken_quizzes')
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='taken_quizzes')
    score = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    least_bid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    confirmed = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Not Confirmed')
```

Comment: Could you please show `Supplier` model?

Answer (score 0):

`supplier` is a read only field. So there's no point in adding it to the data dict, since it will never be used.

You shouldn't be modifying the post data anyway - there's a reason that is immutable. Instead [pass it in when saving](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save):

```
serializer = takenquizSerializer(data=request.data)

if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save(supplier_id=supplier.user_id, score=0, quiz=pk)
```

Comment: I tried that too but it returns : {
    "score": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "quiz": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}